# Serialize a Map into an array of couple using Jackson in Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

First of all, I know what I am trying to do can be done using a custom `JsonSerializer`, but I'd like to know whether there is a less boilerplate code solution for this.

In `Spring MVC`, I'd like to serialize a `Map` into a list of couples. Let's say I'd like to return such a `Map`:

```
Map<String, String> res = new HashMap<>();
res.put("key1", "value1");
res.put("key2", "value2");
```

The default serialization result will give a `JSON` like this:

```
{key1: value1, key2: value2}
```

Is there a way to have instead something like this, without using a custom `JsonSerializer`?

```
[{key: "key1", value: "value1"}, {key: "key2", value: "value2"}]
```

I'm using `Spring-Boot 1.3` with default versions of `Spring MVC` and `Jackson`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I prefered a reusable solution, and could not find a standard solution, I implemented it with a custom `JsonSerializer`, as follows:

```
public class MapToCoupleArraySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Map<?, ?>>{

    @Override
    public void serialize(Map<?, ?> value, JsonGenerator generator,
            SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        generator.writeStartArray();
        for (Entry<?, ?> entry : value.entrySet()){
            generator.writeStartObject();
            generator.writeObjectField("key", entry.getKey());
            generator.writeObjectField("value", entry.getValue());
            generator.writeEndObject();
        }       
        generator.writeEndArray();
    }    
}
```

and use it in the traditionnal `Spring` way:

```
public class MyClassToSerialize{

    @JsonSerialize(using = MapToCoupleArraySerializer .class)
    private Map<Key, Value> recipes;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try to serialize `entries` instead of the map itself :

```
Map.Entry[] entries = myMap.entrySet().toArray(new Map.Entry[]{});
```

I didn't try it, but the result should be similar enough to what you want.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. How would you do if the `Map` is an attribute of another object? Should I convert this object into a **DTO** containing the `entries`?